# Adding a fading scrim to a CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library

How do you get a fading scrim on the CollapsingToolbar Layout's title?

I've successfully set the text size and color using the `app:expandedTitleTextAppearance` attribute, but can't figure out how to give the text a background.

I know it's possible because I can see that WhatsApp has done it in its Group Info screen.

Comment: Hi! I've read that you manage to do this, I'm exactly facing this problem, could you help me?

Comment: I did not end up doing this. It looks like WhatsApp might be using their own implementation of the Collapsing Toolbar Layout

Comment: I managed to add the overlay translucent effect on the upper side of the collapsing toolbar (it's good because my up caret is white and with light images was very difficult to see) but the bottom overlay effect I don't know how to do it, it turns out that if you set the `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` the view does not appear in the layout (not a view nor a textview or anything else, only with bottom)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way I have been able to do it is to place a view behind the toolbar like this:

```
<View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="@drawable/shape_scrim"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
     app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

With the shape_scrim.xml looks like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:startColor="#BB000000"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

bkurzius implementation worked for me after I added a z-axis translation value to the View containing the shape_scrim.

```
<View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="@drawable/shape_scrim"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:translationZ="8dp"/>

<ImageView
    ...
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bkurzius, your implementation worked for me after I changed the shape_scrim.xml like this (makes fading effect from top to bottom of its container view), source code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#BB000000"
        android:startColor="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

And my CollapsingToolbar looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat
                android:id="@+id/background_collapsing_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_scrim"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to make use of **app:contentScrim=""**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        **app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"**
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewGroupAvatar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bonga_avatar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/imageview_background_gradient_profile" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/eight_margin"
                android:padding="@dimen/eight_margin"
                android:tint="#901E78"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbarTextViewGroupName"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="Group Profile" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```